# Running facebook application on smartphone

Tags: wpf, facebook, smartphone

i have a general question : i'd like to develop a facebook application using wpf(the aim is running a game-like application on facebook).
does wpf application works on smartphone ? 
i want to know how can i make this application to run on smartphones when a user login to facebook via smartphone. 
i don't want to develop android / iphone / ... application that connects with facebook.
i have looked it up, but couldn't find anything that helps me in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, WPF is only for Windows based desktop applications, the .NET platform which supports smart phones is Windows Phone 7 (WP7), but that only works for windows smartphones.

Objective C has quite a bit of animation options and is generally used for this type of thing.

Check out [this article](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9178684/Developing_for_the_iPhone_and_Android_The_pros_and_cons) which outlines options for smartphone development.

Comment: hi jimmy, thanks for the response. so from this article its quite clear that developing a facebook application that would run in smartphones(within facebook app) is not possible. i'm just having a hard time choosing an api to start with. for starters, i'd like just to develop a game-like app to facebook in .net